# I am trying to deploy micro service in ECS fargate getting below error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Stopped | CannotStartContainerError: ResourceInitializationError: unable to create new container: mount callback failed on /tmp/containerd-mount2307274170: open /tmp/containerd-mount2307274170/etc/passwd: no such file or directory

Can some one help me out to resolve the issue

Comment: Can you post your task definition? Seems to be something wrong with the way your mounting something.

Comment: I have the same problem - trying to run ASP.net core on Linux on Fargate

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with batch job running as ECS task on fargate.
Apparantly the image being built was based on windows OS, i.e. the docker was configured to build windows-based images.

Same code when built from a docker which is configured to build Linux based images and pushed to ECR, the issue got resolved.

Please check the type of image you are building.
One way to validate this is to use linux specific base image in the docker file. Example: FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0.22-jammy AS base

If the above line gives error saying linux is not supported or similar, during docker build, then you might want to check docker settings.